# Set maximum retries in google cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying to set a custom number of retries if a task fails in Google Cloud Run. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-retries#command-line), I should use `--max-retries` to set the numbers of tres. I tried to set it with the following command

```
gcloud beta run deploy ${SAMPLE} \
  --set-env-vars GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT} \
  --image gcr.io/${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}/${SAMPLE} --timeout=30m  --cpu 4 --memory 4Gi --concurrency 1 --execution-environment gen2 --max-retries 2
```

But I got an error

```
unrecognized arguments:
  --max-retries
```

I documention is also mentioned that the value can be modified in the console by `"Click Container, Variables, Connections, Security to expand the job properties page."`, but I am also not able to find this in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes flags are only available via the CLI and not via the GUI. In this case the --max-retries is in Beta hence why it's not in the GUI yet. It's possible the GUI features haven't rolledout everywhere yet

Comment: I tried with the beta CLI and got an error. I updated my question with the command I used.

Comment: Ahh sorry i just double checked. That feature is only available for jobs. Not for apps